# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' when using sourcemod

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets

I've been looking for about 30 mins, because this was happening with sourcemod rankme plugin on my CS:GO server and found the solution which I wanted to share with you

Answer (score 0):

The thing is it uses the wrong path to MySQL socket. This should help:

```
ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```